# decoding an encrypted string in java

Tags: java, encryption, character-encoding, decode

I am trying to decode the string encoded by the function below. I tried to reverse the encryption by doing `c -=  c-i`, but it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone please explain how does this work?

```
public static String encode(String message){
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0;i<message.length();i++){
            char c = message.charAt(i);
            b.append(c +=  c+i);
        }
        return b.reverse().toString();
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand the reason for downvote?

Comment: Arithmetic on character codes is a bit sketchy (@Elliot alludes to unstated conditions for this algorithm). That's why encryption libraries take in bytes and put out bytes. If you want to convert text to bytes, you'd apply a character encoding (such as UTF-8), and visa versa. If you want to handle encryped bytes (or any non-text bytes) as text, you'd use Base64 or similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your encoding **is** reversible (for small messages and some set of the charset), but your formula is incorrect. First, reverse the message (to decode). Then iterate the characters. Subtract `i` from the current value, and then divide by `2`. Like,

```
public static String decode(String message) {
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(message).reverse();
    StringBuilder o = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length(); i++) {
        char c = b.charAt(i);
        c -= i;
        c /= 2;
        o.append(c);
    }
    return o.toString();
}
```

Math: `c += c + i`; is equivalent to `c = (2 * c) + i`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Now i understand the math behind it